# confirm will not trigger with empty textfield validation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope someone can help me with this, I have a form with a variable amount of text fields and want to check if they are filled in upon submitting the form.

My code is as follows:

```
$('#complete_order').click(function(){

    var isValid = true;

    $("input[class='article_code']").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == "" || $(this).val() == null) {
            isValid = false;
            $(this).closest('tr').find('.message').hide().html("Article code is empty.").fadeIn('fast');
        }
    });

    if(isValid == true) {
        if (!confirm('Are you sure you want to place this order?')) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $("form[name='order_supplier']").submit();
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that when all fields are filled in the confirm will not trigger, in fact is does nothing at all so no submit either.

Am I using the confirm function the wrong way?

/edit Here is the HTML code

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="order_supplier" name="order_supplier" action="?action=send_order">
    <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr><td>Supplier</td><td><select name="supplier"><option></option></select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Article code</td><td><input type="text" class="article_code" name="article_code[]"></td><td><span class="message"></span></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Description</td><td><input type="text" class="article_description" name="article_description[]" value="No article id specified" readonly></td></tr>
        <tr class="article_quantity"><td>Quantity</td><td><select name="article_quantity[]"><option></option></select></td></tr>

        <tr><td></td><td><button type="button" name="addfields" id="addfields">Add article</button></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td><td><button type="button" name="complete_order" id="complete_order">Place order</button></td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Is the `#complete_order` button a submit button? This code should ideally run under the `submit` event of the containing form. Could you please add your HTML to the question.

Comment: What @RoryMcCrossan said. Try .submit - and if it still doesn't work - paste some HTML in here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan The #complete_order is a normal button, when I use a submit button the form gets submitted right away. The HTML is pretty big and gets build by php functions so I'm not sure which part I should add

Comment: It looks like something goes wrong at `if(isValid == true)` because when I remove this condition the confirm does get triggered

Comment: can you please share HTML code coz the script works fine

Comment: check the following demo your script is working fine there might be prob in your HTML https://jsfiddle.net/y8b9t365/

Comment: @RRR thanks, yeah I tried using my code in jsfiddle and it worked, so I checked my html and added it but I can't find the problem

Comment: yea its strange it works if i copy paste your code to fiddle maybe some other methods conflicting... did you check the console for errors?

Comment: Yes, there were no errors. Is there maybe another way to make this code work like if there are empty fields do this, else open the confirm dialog.

Comment: @RRR, oke I fixed it. It was a really stupid mistake I only checked with the fields that were added after the original fields because those were the only ones that would show the error message, so I forgot that the original field also got checked even though it didn't show the empty field message. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: glad you fixed it :)